# Neo4j 2.0.0M04, using Cypher and new indexes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Two questions about using Cypher and the new (2.0) indexes:

1. [The only queries that the manual lists](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.0-M04/query-schema-index.html) for indexes are the `DROP/CREATE INDEX ON` queries. Is there a way (using Cypher) to query for all existing indexes? I know that in the console you can do `index --indexes`, but that only returns legacy indexes (or that's the way it seems to me). Edit: Even more usefully, I found the console command 'schema', which at least gives a listing of indexes.

   I have seen that it's possible at least to look for [all the indexes associated to a label in REST](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.0-M04/rest-api-schema-indexes.html), but I was hoping for a way to do so in Cypher.
2. The `START` query seems entirely deprecated if you're not using legacy indexes and not referring to nodes by their id (which the docs have seemed to indicate is a bad idea). So in neo4j 2.0, is there any use for `START`?

Comment: Are you able to elaborate on where the docs indicate that using `START n=node(id)` is a bad idea?

Comment: Certainly--on the [manual page for `START`](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.0-M04/query-start.html) there is a note under 14.1.1 which says that "Neo4j reuses its internal ids when nodes and relationships are deleted, which means it’s bad practice to refer to them this way. Instead, use application generated ids."

Comment: I think that is a little misleading, and depends very much on your data model. All they are saying really, is Id's are reused once nodes are removed from the system. For example, I have nodes that act as pointers to particular data. I could manually create an index for these nodes, but I find it much easier to simply grab the Id, and use it for various queries.

Comment: That seems fine for personal use, but completely unsuitable for a production environment. Between two transactions you have no guarantees that the node with a given ID is the one you believe it is, and inside of a transaction there are better ways to reference it.

Comment: As I said, it depends on your model. I don't perform any node deletions in my application, so it is completely fine for production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to webinar "What's New in Neo4j 2.0" (http://watch.neo4j.org/video/72069694) There is no longer any use for
    Start.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the video seems to indicate that `START` is optional, not that there is no use for it.

But thank you for that link. It's very helpful to get a sense of the idiomatic ways to use neo4j.

Comment: Well, in some cases, especially for addressing legacy indexes, you still need the `START`, but we are trying to get to a point where there are no usecases left for it.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the console you can use `schema` command to list all active schema indexes and constraints.
2. No, `start` command is depreciated in Neo4j 2.0 and higher.